# NullPointerException when calculating the Average using Stream API

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap, java-stream

I have a list of `Student` objects. Each of them contains a map of subjects and points earned as `Double`.

```
public class Student {
    public int student_id;
    public String name;
    Map<String, Double> examPoints = new HashMap<String, Double>();

    public Student(int student_id, String name) {
        this.student_id = student_id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setExamPoints(String name, Double points){

        examPoints.put(name, points);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to calculate the **average score** of all the students in a specific subject using Java Streams.

`main()`

```
Student studentOne = new Student(1, "Ole");
studentOne.setExamPoints("Programmering", 20.0);
studentOne.setExamPoints("Math", 10.0);
studentOne.setExamPoints("Algdat", 25.5);

Student studentTwo = new Student(2, "Åge");
studentTwo.setExamPoints("Fysikk", 12.0);
studentTwo.setExamPoints("Math", 15.0);
studentTwo.setExamPoints("Algdat", 65.5);

Student studentThree = new Student(3, "Per");
studentThree.setExamPoints("Matte", 24.2);
studentThree.setExamPoints("Gym", 45.0);
studentThree.setExamPoints("Algdat", 29.3);

Student studentFour = new Student(4, "Svein");
studentFour.setExamPoints("Programmering", 90.0);
studentFour.setExamPoints("AdvJava", 99.0);
studentFour.setExamPoints("Science", 29.5);

ArrayList<Student> allStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();
allStudents.add(studentOne);
allStudents.add(studentTwo);
allStudents.add(studentThree);
allStudents.add(studentFour);


double algdatAverage = allStudents.stream()
    .mapToDouble(s -> s.examPoints.get("Algdat"))
    .average()
    .getAsDouble();

double mathAverage = allStudents.stream()
    .mapToDouble(s -> s.examPoints.get("Math"))
    .average()
    .getAsDouble();
```

I'm getting a `NullPointerException`:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.lambda$main$0(Main.java:39)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$6$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:246)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.DoublePipeline.collect(DoublePipeline.java:514)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.DoublePipeline.average(DoublePipeline.java:467)
    at Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

I'm using Java 11.

Comment: I would recommend you to debug your application and to use [peek](https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-peek-api) for sole purpose to debug your streams

Comment: Not everyone of your Student objects has a Map entry for the key `"Algdat"` so s.examPoints.get("Algdat") will return `null` for your 4th student. You can either first filter your stream to only include those that have this key in their ExamPoints map, or you use a map function that returns a default value if the key isn't found instead of the standard get method.

Comment: `studentFour` has no entry for `"Algdat"`.

Comment: oh, so i would first filter all the students to remove the ones that dont have algdat, then i would do ```mapToDouble(s -> s.examPoints.get("Algdat")).average().getAsDouble();``` on the result of that instead, that makes more sense

Comment: like @f1sh mentioned. so you are trying to get an average on an array with a null value and getting a NullPointerException. Add "Algdat" to StudentThree or use a condition in .mapToDouble like if(!s.examPoints.get("Algdat")) { return 0;} else {return s.examPoints.get("Algdat"))

Comment: @catfish to me another tricky part in your question is *average score of all the students in a specific subject* here do you need to count other students also who do not have that specific subject? If not then given and is already solid , if yes then you can use this `allStudents.stream().mapToDouble(s -> s.examPoints.getOrDefault("Algdat", 0.0))`

Comment: Please improve your title, this question will never be found by googling

Answer (score 2):

Filter first:

```
double asDouble = allStudents.stream()
.filter(s -> s.examPoints.containsKey("Algdat"))
.mapToDouble(s -> s.examPoints.get("Algdat"))
.average()
.getAsDouble();
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `public` fields. And also avoid manipulating with data structures that belong to a particular object outside this object, learn about the [*Information expert principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)#Information_expert).

The *map* containing exam points has to be *encapsulated* in the `Student` object. Instead of accessing its values directly, it would be cleaner to introduce a method which returns points for a particular exam, let's say `getExamPoints()`.

*Sidenote: follow the [*Java Naming Conventions*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), avoid using names like `student_id`.*

```
public class Student {
    private int studentId;
    private String name;
    private Map<String, Double> examPoints = new HashMap<>();
    
    public Student(int studentId, String name) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public void setExamPoints(String examName, Double points) {
        examPoints.put(examName, points);
    }
    
    public Double getExamPoints(String examName) {
        return examPoints.get(examName);
    }
}
```

`getExamPoints()` will return `null` if the *map* `examPoints` doesn't contain the entry for the given exam. While streaming over a list of students, we can use `filter()` operation to ensure that there wouldn't be NPE while calculating the average.

And that's how the method that returns the average score for a particular exam might be implemented:

```
public static double getAverageExamPoints(List<Student> students,
                                          String examName) {
    return students.stream()
        .mapToDouble(student -> student.getExamPoints(examName))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull) 
        .average()
        .orElse(0); // or .orElseThrow() to throw NoSuchElementException if there's no data in the stream
}
```

**Note:** `getAsDouble()` will throw `NoSuchElementException` if the stream is empty, which is not obvious to reader of the code. If throwing the exception in such a case is a desired behavior - use `orElseThrow()` instead. See the [*API note*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html#getAsDouble()).

> **API Note:**
>
> The preferred alternative to this method is `orElseThrow()`.